# JS - Google maps displays grey on window load, displays properly on resize, why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a map that is inside a bootstrap tab-panel, and it's displaying grey which is obviously not desired. However, the second I resize the window, it immediately loads accurately. I am using the same script for the map in another page on the same site, however on that page it's not in a tab pane - and it loads fine. I tried re-ordering the scripts on the page as I thought something may be interfering, but it didn't help. Note I also tried adding the line `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` as I read another post on here with a similar issue, but it also didn't help.

If I initially click on the tab, I see this:

[image: before]

and If I resize the window I get this:

[image: after]

JS for the map:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.246292,-123.116226),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          styles: [...]
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The scripts are loaded into the head of the html like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/glyphcon.png" sizes="96x96"/>
<title><?php echo "" . $name . "" ?></title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="js/map.js"></script>
```

And the tab-panel with the map div is like this:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="address">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, with any CSS/HTML required.  Or search this site for issues with tabs that are hidden to start with, then displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tab is not visible during map initialization/loading  this is the normal behavior, you should invoke `resize` during tab click operation or better call the (re) initialize function when you click the tab.